# Codebase error?

Tags: joomla

Received Warning Message:
New Codebase version detected.  You might want to visit upgrade screen to upgrade the database.

When I click on the link it takes me to another error message:

```
An error has occurred.
0 <div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css);
@import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);
</style>
<div class="messages status no-popup">
<div class="icon red-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
<span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span>
<div class="crm-section crm-error-message">CiviCRM 4.6.4 requires MySQL trigger privileges.</div>
<p><a href="https://powerengineering.org/administrator/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p> </div> </div>
<script language="JavaScript">function toggle( element ) { 
    var className = element.className;
    if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') {
        element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else {
        element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block';
    }
} </script></pre>
```

I contacted my host server and their reply was: "It seems to be an issue with the plugin itself."

Joomla ver:  3.4.1
CiviCRM ver:  4.6.4
mysql: 5.5.43
php:  5.4.39-1

Comment: Did you ask your host to ensure you have MySQL trigger privileges?

Answer (score 1):

As @Coleman already pointed out MySQL trigger privilege is a requirement for CiviCRM to run. So technically your host serveris correct, the message is from the plugin. But it is a **requirement** for CiviCRM to run, not an issue that needs to be fixed in the code.

Check this page https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/ for the technical requirements for CiviCRM to run, and you might want to point this out to your host server and check if they meet those requirements?